# Smooth end to transition from a CSS animation triggered by :hover

Tags: css, animation, hover

I had an idea for nesting CSS animations for infinite cycles where the duration of each cycle is a different prime number so the accumulative effect is a nice non-repetitive animation (hover over the logo with a webkit browser for an idea: http://jsbin.com/usabop/2)

The problem is that when :hover state ends everything instantly jumps back to the original state.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions to make this a smoother transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, with the way the CSS animations work, there is no easy way to do this. You could use the `animation-play-state` property, but that would simply freeze the animation at its current frame when you are no longer hovering.

My recommendation would be to use JavaScript to add a class on hover, which then triggers one full cycle of the animation.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried that would be the answer. Good tip on animation-play-state, I didn't know that property :)